# state of AsyncTask when the activity gets destroyed

Tags: android

In my main activity I have an `AsyncTask` running which in `postExecute()` updates a `ListView.`
Now before `postExecute()` gets called if my activity gets destroyed due to any reason what would be the state of the `AyncTask`. `onPostExecute()` UI updations will throw exception.

One way I thought is to cancel the ayncTask in `onDestory()`. But if the asynctask is in postExecute when on destroy gets called how to handle it.

Comment: You can check your activity is not finishing onPostExecute, and only update the UI if not.

Comment: @KunalS.Kushwah No it won't!! AsyncTask is a background running process so its `doInbackground()` will be running though Activity is destroyed!

Comment: @KenWolf How to check that?

Comment: `if (activity.isFinishing()) { // do UI stuff }` replace `activity` with a reference to your activity of course. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()

Answer (score 1):

> But if the asynctask is in postExecute when on destroy gets called how to handle it.

This case simply cannot happen, because both methods are called on the UI Thread, meaning one is finished before the other is called.

When your UI is no longer available (in `onDestroy`), cancel your `AsyncTask`.

In `onPostExecute` you can check the cancel status of the `AsyncTask`. You can also check `isFinishing` on the `Activity`.

Answer (score -1):

Some how u can handle u r code exception like this,U can handle exception in the AsyncTask

```
public abstract class ExceptionAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

    private Exception exception=null;
    private Params[] params;

    @Override
    final protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
        try {
            this.params = params; 
            return doInBackground();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }

    abstract protected Result doInBackground() throws Exception;

    @Override
    final protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        onPostExecute(exception, result);
    }

    abstract protected void onPostExecute(Exception exception, Result result);

    public Params[] getParams() {
        return params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit

Comment: We override doInBackground in our subclass to do background work, happily throwing Exceptions where needed. You are then forced to implement onPostExecute (because it's abstract) and this gently reminds you to handle all types of Exception, which are passed as parameter. In most cases, Exceptions lead to some type of ui output, so onPostExecute is a perfect place to do that.